# Show a product attribute under price - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I'm trying to show a product attribute underneath the price in Magento 2. I have overridden the template by adding it to my theme:

```
Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

This is the contents of this file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
    <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
<?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
    <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
    <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
    data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
    data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
    class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>"
><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?></span>
<?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
    <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

So I would assume that I need to add this at the top of the file:

```
<?php
  $_product = $block->getProduct();
  $myattr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
```

Then use the following to include it where I need it

```
<?php if($myattr != "") { echo $myattr } ?>
```

But I just get a blank page when I view it on the front end. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Try to overwrite vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml file to add new block. It may work

Comment: I know how to add blocks via XML but not product attributes. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Is it needed every where at price displayed ?

Comment: Yes, underneath every price :)

Comment: You mean every page ?

Comment: Can you please confirm that your attribute has 
Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront = yes

Comment: So you can overwrite catalog_category_view.xml and catalog_product_view.xml file to solve this

Comment: Underneath every price on every page. Yes the attribute is visible on catalog and storefront.

Comment: Can you please check status of indexing also or you can run indexing also. Because sometimes it is not displaying because of indexing also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with a separate phtml file and layout XML as describe below.

Assumed "model_number" is the custom attribute that you want to display and your custom theme is "VendorName_customtheme"

step 1:
create ***/app/design/frontend/VendorName/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml***

File **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>              
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
       <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.mycustom.attribute" as="model_number" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_attrib.phtml" after="product.info.price" />                    
        </referenceContainer>                   
    </body>
</page>
```

step 2: create **/app/design/frontend/VendorName/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom_attrib.phtml**

File : **custom_attrib.phtml**

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<div class="">
    <?php
    $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('model_number');                                
    if ($attribute) 
    { 
     $attr_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>   
     <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Model no.')). $attr_value ?>
    <?php } ?>  
</div>
```

step 3: Run this CLI command  from your magento root

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

[image]

Comment: I guess it's working product detail page only.

Comment: Yes. What other places do you need to display this custom attribute.

Comment: Ordog needs to display every where that means all pages

Comment: This is great and certainly a step in the right direction but as @VigneshBala mentioned I need to show this under the prices for Related Products, Upsells and on category pages too.

Comment: A) You may need to override Blocks for  Related Products, Upsells Products to show custom attribute. Also need to update phtml with custom code to display product custom attribute.

B) To display product custom attribute in category pages, same code will works .
 Please make sure "Used in Product Listing" Storefront Properties for the custom attribute must set to Yes from Admin panel product attribute section.

Comment: I amended this for a slightly different end result but this angle of approach helped me massively. Thank you!

Comment: So out of all other answers, your is the one I could even follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current product (Magento 2.3.x) within price template phtml using

```
$product = $block->getSaleableItem();
```